# #define LOG_MSG(...) for debugging

Tags: c, debugging, c-preprocessor

How does the following code work?

```
#define ENABLE_DEBUG 1

#if ENABLE_DEBUG
    #define LOG_MSG printf
#else
    #define LOG_MSG(...)
#endif
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on the value of `ENABLE_DEBUG`, `LOG_MSG` is either defined to be an alias for `printf()` or it is defined as a no-op macro. It is implied that you can change the value to `0` to disable debugging. This is a common technique for making it easy to switch between debugging builds which display lots of output and release builds which are quiet.

```
#define LOG_MSG printf
```

This makes it an alias for `printf()`.

```
#define LOG_MSG(...)    /* empty */
```

And this defines it as an empty macro. Notice that here it has a set of parentheses, which means the macro takes parameters. It has nothing afterwards which means it expands to absolutely nothing. And the `...` indicates that this macro can take a [varying number of arguments](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html). This syntax is a C99 extension so it may not be available on older C compilers.

```
LOG_MSG("file not found\n");
```

The result is that a `LOG_MSG()` call will either print a message or do nothing depending on whether logging is enabled.

```
// If ENABLE_DEBUG is non-zero, a debugging printout:
printf("file not found\n");

// If ENABLE_DEBUG is zero, an empty statement:
;
```

For what it's worth, whoever authored this macro could've done a better job by replacing the first definition with one using the `...` syntax (which he/she is clearly familiar with), printing to stderr instead of stdout:

```
#define LOG_MSG(...) fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses the preprocessor to change code before compilation.
If `ENABLE_DEBUG` is defined as 1, whenever the preprocessor sees

```
LOG_MSG("something happened");
```

It will replace it with

```
printf("something happened");
```

If it is defined as 0, or not defined it will replace it with nothing (as the other answer that has just been published says).